# Lagrange multipliers on Banach spaces

Tags: functional-analysis, optimization, banach-spaces, lagrange-multiplier, frechet-derivative

Omitting technical details, if we want to find a local extremum $x_1$ of a functional $f:E_1\to\mathbb R$ on a Banach space $E_1$ with constraint $g(x_1)=0$, where $g:E_1\to E_2$ and $E_2$ is another Banach space, we may solve $${\rm D}f(x_1)+\lambda{\rm D}g(x_1)=0\tag1,$$ where $\lambda\in E_2'$.

Can we incorporate $g(x_1)=0$ and $(1)$ into one equation $${\rm D}\mathcal L(x_1,\lambda)=0\tag2,$$ where $$\mathcal L(x_1,\lambda):=f(x_1)+\lambda g(x_1)$$ as it is [explained on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_multiplier#Single_constraint) in the Euclidean space case?

It should be true, but the Fréchet derivative in $(2)$ involves Fréchet derivatives of functions on $E_2'$ which seems to be quite complicated and maybe some identification is necessary.

Comment: The functional $\lambda\in E_2'$ is a function on $E_2$ as $\lambda\colon E_2\to\mathbb{R}$, so I do not see any problem with differentiating the composition $\lambda\circ g$.

Comment: @A.Γ. Yes, this is involved in the Fréchet derivative wrt the first argument. We should have $${\rm D}\mathcal L(x_1,\lambda)(y_1,\varphi_2)={\rm D}_1\mathcal L(x_1,\lambda)y_1+{\rm D}_2\mathcal L(x_1,\lambda)\varphi_2$$ for all $x_1\in E_1$ and $\varphi_2\in E_2'$. How can we compute ${\rm D}_2\mathcal L(x_1,\lambda)\varphi_2$? I guess it involves the derivative of $\langle\;\cdot\;,g(x_1)\rangle\in E_2''$.

Answer (score 1):

Lagrangian function in any space (finite on infinite dimension ) is

$$\mathcal L(x_1,\lambda):=f(x_1)+ \langle  \lambda , g(x_1) \rangle $$

Yes. You need to consider $weak-star$ topology on $E'_2$. Then in this case you have $E''_2 = E_2$

In general when you assume $E'_2$ equipped with operator-norm The derivative of lagrangian with respect to  $\lambda$ at a fix point $\bar \lambda$,  is a bounded linear functional, say  $\phi : E'_2 \to R$ defined by $\phi(z) = \langle z ,g(x) \rangle  $. Setting this $\phi$ equals zero gives you again $g(x)=0$, so no problem in this case too. Assuming $weak-star$ topology on $E'_2$ gives you $\phi : E_2 \to R$, which is standard definition.

Then derivative with respect to $x$ gives equation (1). While the derivative with respect to $\lambda$ gives you the constraint $g(x)=0$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I'm not very familiar with this stuff, but am I correct that if $E_2$ is reflexive, we can stay with the "usual" topology on $E_2'$ induced by the operator norm?

Comment: Could you show what the Fréchet derivative of $\mathcal L$ wrt $\lambda$ is? I've got problems computing it.

Comment: The space doesn't have to be reflexive, or even normed space. That's always correct.   I edited my answer.

Comment: If $h(\varphi):=\langle\varphi,x\rangle$ for $\varphi\in E_2'$ and some fixed $x\in E_2$. Then the Fréchet derivative ${\rm D}h$ of $h$ is constantly $h$ (since $h\in E_2''$). That's what you've used to differentiate $\mathcal L$ wrt $\lambda$, right?

Comment: When you say "assuming weak*-topology on $E_2'$ gives you $\phi:E_2\to\mathbb R$", how exactly is $\phi$ identified with its former definition?

Comment: @0xbadf00d If $h(\phi)=\langle\phi,x\rangle$ then $Dh=h=\langle\cdot,x\rangle$ as long as the latter is continuous. Any topology where it is continuous would work. However, the most important part of the necessary condition is ${\rm D_x}\mathcal L(x,\lambda)=0$. Would you really need ${\rm D}_\lambda\mathcal L(x,\lambda)=0$ simply to refer to $g(x)=0$? Anyhow, the Gateaux derivative is enough for that, and it uses only the topology in $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: @A.Γ. I don't get what you wrote after "the most important part of the necessary condition is ${\rm D_x}\mathcal L(x,\lambda)=0$". You mean we don't need ${\rm D}_\lambda\mathcal L(x,\lambda)=0$ to conclude $g(x)=0$? And I don't understand what you wrote abut the Gâteaux dervative. Would be great if you can elaborate on that.

Comment: It's clear to me hat $${\rm D}_1\mathcal L(x,λ)y={\rm D}f(x)y+\langleλ,{\rm D}g(x)y\rangle\;\;\;\text{for all }(x,λ)\in E_1\times E_2'\text{ and }y\in E_2$$ and $${\rm D}_2\mathcal L(x,λ)μ=\langleμ,g(x)\rangle\;\;\;\text{for all }(x,λ)\in E_1\times E_2'\text{ and }μ\in E_2'.$$ Clearly, ${\rm D}_1\mathcal L(x,λ)=0$ is $(1)$ and ${\rm D}_2\mathcal L(x,λ)=0$ is equivalent to $g(x)=0$. However, what's claimed is that $(1)$ and $g(x)=0$ are equivalent to ${\rm D}\mathcal L(x,λ)=0$, where $${\rm D}\mathcal L(x,λ)(y,μ)={\rm D}_1\mathcal L(x,λ)y+{\rm D}_2\mathcal L(x,λ)\mu.$$ How do we see that?

Comment: @0xbadf00d Obviously ${\rm D}\mathcal L(x,λ)=0$ is equivalent to ${\rm D}_1\mathcal L(x,λ)=0$ and ${\rm D}_2\mathcal L(x,λ)=0$ (since it must hold for all $y$ and $\mu$). The first condition is [KKT gradient condition for stationarity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karush%E2%80%93Kuhn%E2%80%93Tucker_conditions#Necessary_conditions), the second one is the primal feasibility $g(x)=0$.

Comment: @A.Γ. Yes, you're right. They are obviously equivalent. I guess what's confusing me is the discussion about the topology on $E_2'$. I don't see why we should consider the weak*-topology on $E_2'$ instead of the strong operator topology. With the latter, ${\rm D}_2\mathcal L(x,\lambda):E_2'\to\mathfrak L(E_2',\mathbb R)=E_2''$ which seems to be fine. So, I don't get the point of considering weak*-topology.

Comment: @0xbadf00d To claim existence of the Fréchet derivative of $h(\phi)=\langle\phi,x\rangle$, it has to be continuous. The weak* topology is the (weakest) topology that keeps linear functionals $E_2\subset E_2''$ to be still continuous. To my mind, this construction is not really necessary here as the continuity is the only property we need. The weak* topology is often useful when we are chasing continuity + *compactness* (to ensure existence of the optimal solution). I would replace this troublesome $D_\lambda L=0$ with the condition $g(x)=0$, as the latter is basically the same, but easier.

Comment: @A.Γ. You mean that if $E_2'$ is equipped with the weak* topology, any linear function $E_2'\to\mathbb R$ is continuous (and hence an element of $E_2''$)? And further, if I got you right, the problem is that (with $E_2'$ being equipped with the strong operator topology) the thing I denoted by ${\rm D}_\lambda\mathcal L(x,\lambda):E_2'\to\mathbb R$ is only linear, but not continuous and hence is *not* the Fréchet derivative of $\mathcal L$ wrt $\lambda$ at $(x,\lambda)$. Is that what you mean? If so, what else is ${\rm D}_\lambda\mathcal L(x,\lambda)$ in that case?